# Adding a package to be imported to ROS

Tags: ros, rospy

I'm trying to import a module named pytesseract into a Python file in a package I made. However, I get a No Module Found error. The same error doesn't occur for numpy, and I noticed that numpy was in the requirements.txt file. My thinking is that I would have to add pytesseract to a file like CMakeLists or package.xml. What am I actually supposed to do?

Comment: You didn't list which version of ubuntu/ros you're using, but it's likely using python2. Make sure you didn't install it with pip3. ROS won't compile python, when it runs a python node, it calls the script as an executable by whichever python is the default executor for it. That python exec is the one that also finds the `import`s. requirements.txt is just a file that people call pip install on, it won't automatically do anything in ros.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that makes sense. So I changed the shebang in my python file to say python2 (since that's what most of the ROS packages are in), and I ran `pip install pytesseract` and it installed it but I still get the same ImportError. Am I missing a step?

Comment: Try just opening a python(2) terminal, and try to import it. Note it also [has some weird import rule?](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/)

Comment: Looks like that was it. I had to `pip2 install` it since ROS uses Python 2. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'll just summarize this in an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a python module/package is failing to be imported into ros, it is most-likely an issue with *which* python: which python is ros using, and which one you used to install. 
Normally, of course, you would make a special env for your python project, specifying the version, but ros strongly prefers to use system level definitions. And (before ubuntu 20) strictly preferred python 2. (Since/if/when ros is the only project using system python, this works out fine for other projects).

Ros executables (python scripts) use whichever shebang you give it, or whichever python is set as default; you can try running that (python2) terminal outside of ros and attempt importing to narrow the cause. importing ros packages will fail if you use the wrong python; likewise, if you pip3/pip install a python3 package, importing it in python2 will fail (due to default python_path settings).